Create a year-month column in Python YYYYMM format
I have multiple years which are created using the following statement
 range(datetime.now().year - 1, datetime.now().year + 1)
giving the following output
2023
2024

And I have a month column created by range(1, 13)
1
2
.
.
.
12

I want to create the following column:
202301
202302
202303
202304
.
.
.
202411
202412

I tried the following:
range(datetime.now().year - 1, datetime.now().year + 1) * 100 + range(1,13)
But since the dimensions of the two ranges aren't equal, it throws an error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'int'.
Does anyone know how to go about this in Python? In my example, I only have two years, in reality I have many years.

Did you try a nested loop?

from datetime import datetime

years = range(datetime.now().year - 4, datetime.now().year + 1)
months = range(1, 13)

year_month_combinations = [year * 100 + month for year in years for month in months]

print(year_month_combinations)

Output will be
[202001, 202002, 202003, 202004, 202005, ......, 202411, 202412]


You can use date_range:
my_range = pd.date_range(
  f"{current_year}-01-01",  # start
  f"{current_year+1}-12-01",  # end
  freq="MS"      # frequency = monthly
).strftime("%Y%m")  # set the format here


And If one would like to avoid hardcoded dates, how can one do that?

You can use f-strings, like f"{current_year}-01-01", if I understand you correctly

Keep it simple and just use a nested loop:
from datetime import datetime

current_year = datetime.now().year

for year in range(current_year - 1, current_year + 1):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        print(year * 100 + month)

